# Unhandled exception

Tags: c++, exception, mfc

I try to implement the game described in the http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/game_programming/same_game_part1_p2.html . Although it worked well initially, from some point till now crashes at runtime while build does not indicate any error. The problem appears as an “Unhandled Exception”-“Access violation reading location” on the line

```
return m_arrColors[m_arrBoard[row][col]];
```

in the function

```
COLORREF CSameGameBoard::GetBoardSpace(int row, int col)
{
  //  Check the bounds of the array
 if(row < 0 || row >= m_nRows || col < 0 || col >= m_nColumns)
   return m_arrColors[0];
 return m_arrColors[m_arrBoard[row][col]];
}
```

Any possible reason?

Update:

The program crashes the first time it tries to access

```
m_arrColors[m_arrBoard[0][0]];
```

m_arrColors and m_arrBoard are defined by the constructor:

```
CSameGameBoard::CSameGameBoard(void)
     :m_arrBoard(NULL),
  m_nColumns(15), m_nRows(15),
  m_nHeight(35),  m_nWidth(35)
 {
  m_arrColors[0] = RGB(  0,  0,  0);
  m_arrColors[1] = RGB(255,  0,  0);
  m_arrColors[2] = RGB(255,255, 64);
  m_arrColors[3] = RGB(  0,  0,255);
}
```

**Update2:** I added the command  SetupBoard(); in the constructor' s body and it worked. However it is not proposed by the tutorial http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/game_programming/same_game_part1_p2.html and initially worked fine in my program without it as well.

Comment: What are `m_arrColors` and `m_arrBoard`? What are `row` and `col` when the crash happens? Pretty sure you're just going out of bounds.

Comment: Have you checked that `m_arrBoard[row][col]` is valid? Have you tried running it in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious reason is that you're accessing invalid indexes of the arrays - either `m_arrColors` or `m_arrBoard`.

For example, if `m_arrBoard` has dimensions `3x3`, and you try to access `m_arrBoard[3][3]`, you'll get a crash (probably, it's actually undefined behavior). - remember that C++ arrays are **0-based**.

Run through it with a debugger, and check to see if this is happening.